# MailKit setting MessageFlags.Deleted freezes the Program

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

I try to use the MailKit IdleClient from here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/ImapIdleExample.cs

and modified the foreach loop in line 98 to this

```
foreach (var message in fetched)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: new message: {1}, UID: {2}", client.Inbox, message.Envelope.Subject, message.UniqueId);
            client.Inbox.AddFlags(message.UniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, false);
            messages.Add(message);
        }
```

When I now run this Program it freezes in the line `client.Inbox.AddFlags` so the line above `Console.WriteLine(....)` only runs one time

Any Idea what might cause this? When I comment the line, the Program runs normal and goes through every message in my Inbox

EDIT:
Just tested other Flags too. They don't work either. Same for removing Flags or Moving the Message to the `SpecialFolder.Trash` using `client.Inbox.MoveTo()`

Answer (score 0):

It was a really simple change. The script from GitHub opened the Inbox in Read-Only Mode (Line 74). Only Change it to FolderAccess.ReadWrite and everything works fine.